# Incorrect overload resolution in for_each_n?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

The following program does not compile:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "1 2 3";
    std::array<int, 3> res;
    std::for_each_n(res.begin(), 3, [&](auto& x) { s >> x; });

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06251064f6d4d046).

The error message

```
main.cpp:10:61: error: no matching function for call to 'for_each_n(std::array<int, 3>::iterator, int, main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>)'

   10 |     std::for_each_n(res.begin(), 3, [&](auto& x) { s >> x; });

      |                                                             ^

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/algorithm:71,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:46:1: note: candidate: 'template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _ForwardIterator, class _Size, class _Function> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, _ForwardIterator> std::for_each_n(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _ForwardIterator, _Size, _Function)'

   46 | for_each_n(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _Size __n, _Function __f);

      | ^~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:46:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:10:61: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided

   10 |     std::for_each_n(res.begin(), 3, [&](auto& x) { s >> x; });
```

suggests that the compiler is picking up the second overload of [`std::for_each_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n), instead as expected the first overload, which takes 3 parameters.
However, copying the "Possible implementation" in the c++ reference of `std::for_each_n`, one gets a compiling program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "1 2 3";
    std::array<int, 3> res;

    auto f = [&](auto& x) { s >> x; };
    auto iter = res.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++iter, ++i)
       f(*iter);

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cea13f1232af7e5).

What is the problem with the first code?

Comment: How is this an algorithm question?

Comment: @ScottHunter I actually wanted to tag the standard <algorithm> library. I corrected the tag.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a *gcc* bug. Indeed, [it compiles on gcc trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/3TPw6G), but not on the latest [9.2 release](https://godbolt.org/z/vFjfwB). I am looking better...

Comment: fwiw, it compiles with VS2019

Comment: Fun, I've actually answered this before.  Closed as a dupe to that post.

Comment: @NathanOliver That answer is two years old, sadly. There's also a link in the cppreference page to a libstdc++ [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/algorithm_impl.h#L82) named `__for_each_n_it_serial`.